# Not Shutting Down Ubuntu 16.04 In HP Laptop

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, hp, bug-reporting

I Recently Installed Ubuntu 16.04 on My HP Laptop which has configuration as 2 GB RAM,3GHz i3 Processor with 2GB Graphic Card Installed.My Problem is that I am not able to shut down my laptop using shutdown command or Using shut down button in the right corner of ubuntu.I am doing shut down it just stuck in the desktop wallpaper and not going to work till then i physically press the power button in my laptop and There is also a issue with my ubuntu is that it hangs many times when i open 6-7 tabs in my google chrome(Nothing is opened other than chrome).I read many solution for ubuntu 14.04 -It was like adding some line of code in my grub files.But Nothing Worked.Please Help Me Out As I am always shutting down ubuntu with the power button.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed itself End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I troubleshoot system slowness seen when viewing PDFs or videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314810/how-do-i-troubleshoot-system-slowness-seen-when-viewing-pdfs-or-videos)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in my HP 15-r250TU by disabling bios option **usb3 preboot** in bios.

Comment: baobab, thank you! It's bugged me for a long time and I just couldn't understand why it was just this one laptop that would not shutdown or reboot. It would instead just hang right before putting itself out. The laptop in question is HP 250 G3 /w a puny Celeron n2840. The distro it's running right now is Linux Lite 5.6 but the same symptom has been there in other distros as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some of these solutions: [Ubuntu 16 reboots seconds after shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760851/ubuntu-16-reboots-seconds-after-shutdown) ?

I also have HP as well as the same problems as you after installing 16.04, and disabling WiFi solved the situation. Temporary at least.